# spring-boot-starter-web vs spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

Tags: rest, spring-boot, dependency-management

I try understand how spring boot is working with html pages. I started following the guide [from spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/). This guide is showing how to work with html page and view technology Thymeleaf. It has page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed it to simple

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

And following [spring boot reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-installation-instructions-for-java) changed `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`(that is not needed now) to `spring-boot-starter-web`, after that I cant see web page. I see result:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). 
No message available.
```

When I come back my Gradle dependencies to `thymeleaf` all works fine.

Controller `src/main/java/hello/GreetingController.java`

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting() {
    return "greeting";
}

}
```

Application `src/main/java/hello/Application.java`

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

Can someone explain me what is difference between `web` and `thymeleaf` dependencies for this only HTML page from `src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html`?

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web` is a dependency of `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`. So `thymeleaf` is based on `web`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should also work with the gradle dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.5.RELEASE` instead of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.2.5.RELEASE`.

`spring-boot-starter-web` functions like a set of basic dependencies needed to develop web-applications with spring. These basic dependencies are:

- jackson-databind
- hibernate-validator
- spring-core
- spring-web
- spring-webmvc
- spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat

`spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` is based on `spring-boot-starter-web` and adds some additional dependencies like the thymeleaf template engine:

- thymeleaf-layout-dialect
- spring-core
- spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-starter-web
- thymeleaf-spring4

You could look this up on mvnrepository.com (for [spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.2.5.RELEASE) and [spring-boot-starter-web](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.5.RELEASE)).

Comment: Ok, if `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.2.5.RELEASE` just add thymeleaf dependency to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.5.RELEASE`, so what I should add to my dependencies for correct working with html page like  `thymeleaf` dependency? Why just `thymeleaf` dependency working with html page? I'm asking what I forgot add for correct working?

Comment: So you only have an index.html. No Controller what so ever?

Comment: I wrote, so I used the guide from [spring.io.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) just so changed page and `spring-boot-starter`. When I use `thymeleaf` all work fine, but why is not working with `starter-web`?

Comment: Have you tried https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot?

Comment: What was your Problem?

Comment: The auto-configuration adds static index.html support. So no needed add it.  `thymeleaf` want see index.html  in `templates` folder.